# XMLParser Get Attribute name

Tags: xml, parsing

I have an XML that looks like this:

```
<Filename **Your_Honor PLUS.mxf** />
<TaskSerial **69604** />
<QCResults>
    <QCIssue>
        <CheckName **Black Frame**s />
        <IssueType **Warning** />
        <Timecode **00:00:33:09** />
        <Description **40 black frames detected** />
        <Comment  />
    </QCIssue>
</QCResults>
```

Using XMLParser in Groovy I'm trying to get the "attributes" parts as the values.

```
File xmlFile = new File(inputFile)
def promoXml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)

String filename = promoXml.Filename
String duration = promoXml.Duration

List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>()
promoXml.QCResults.each { it->
    String current = promoXml.QCResults.QCIssue.toString()
    LOGGER.debug(current)
    errors.add(current)
}
```

And the outputs will be filename, duration, errors.
But I get an error:

> Attribute name "Your_Honor" associated with an element type "FileName"
> must follow by the ' = ' character.

Comment: programming language? framework? version?

Comment: It's Groovy language, I don't know the framework

Comment: The error would indicate that this is not valid XML...

Comment: Yes I know, but this is the XML we get unfotunately and I was wondering if there's any way to overcome that

Comment: You'd have to convert it to valid XML, like `<Filename value='Your_Honor PLUS.mxf' />` or something for an XML parser to read it.

Comment: Try this on bash `sed -re 's/( *<[^ ]+ )(.+)( .*)/\1value="\2"\3/' tmp.txt`